# Sample a signal every X seconds, drop all others

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I want to sample the`startRangingBeaconsSignal` (which fires every ~1 second) every 10 seconds, getting the latest result each time.

From what I understand, this is not the purpose of the throttle function, which actually seems to only sendNext when X amount of time has elapsed without receiving anything.

My attempt below does limit the signal to only sending `next` once every 10 seconds. However, it  doesn't drop interim signals but instead just queues them up to be sent once every 10 seconds. So, long after `startRangingBeaconsSignal` has finished sending, we're still getting drip-fed results from it.

So in essence, I need a way to receive the latest signal once every 10 seconds, and to ignore all others. Any pointers in the right direction gratefully received.

```
[[[[BeaconManager sharedInstance] startRangingBeaconsSignal]
        sample:[RACSignal interval:10 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]]
        subscribeNext:^(NSArray *beacons) {
            // do something with beacons array
        }
    ];
```

Thanks in advance, and apologies for my dodgy terminology.

Comment: "However, it doesn't drop interim signals but instead just queues them up to be sent once every 10 seconds. So, long after `startRangingBeaconsSignal` has finished sending, we're still getting drip-fed results from it". Try a minimal repro of this -- that's not how `sample` works. It does exactly what you're describing -- what are you doing in `subscribeNext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found that the correct solution is to use `sample:` and an interval set to how often you want to (surprise surprise) "sample" the signal:

```
/* countingUpwardsSignal is simply a signal returning x, x+1, x+2, and so on */

NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
RACSignal *countingUpwardsSignal = [[[RACSignal interval:1 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
    startWith:startDate]
    map:^id (NSDate *newDate) {
        return @((int)[newDate secondsLaterThan:startDate]);
    }];


/* fiveSecondsSampleSignal fires once every five seconds, 
   it is used to gate our subscription to countingUpwardsSignal: */

RACSignal *fiveSecondsSampleSignal = [RACSignal interval:5 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];

/* we combine the frequency of fiveSecondsSampleSignal to pull 
   the latest value from countingUpwardsSignal: */
[[countingUpwardsSignal sample:fiveSecondsSampleSignal] subscribeNext:^(id x) {
    NSLog (@"x: %@", x);
}];
```

Which returns:

```
x: 5
x: 10
x: 15
x: 20
x: 25
x: 30
x: 35
x: 40
```

which is exactly what I need.

**EDIT:**
actually, as was pointed out, this was just the same as the original code I posted.. duh . The issue with the original code was that when `thestartRangingBeaconsSignal` stopped firing, `sample:` would just keep returning the last received "next" over and over, so I was getting duplicates. The solution was to `filter` based on a third signal `isRangingSignal`, which would stop the duplicates reaching the subscriber:

```
@weakify(self);
[[[[[BeaconManager sharedInstance] startRangingBeaconsSignal]
    sample:[RACSignal interval:10 onScheduler:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]]
    filter:^BOOL (id value) {
        // HERE we check the value of isRangingSignal - if it's stopped, filter NO.
        NSNumber *isRanging = [[BeaconManager sharedInstance] isRangingSignal].first;
        return isRanging.boolValue;
    }]
    subscribeNext:^(NSArray *beacons) {
        NSLog(@"Received beacons: %i", beacons.count);
    }
];
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the code you posted in the original question?

Comment: There must be some other bug in the original problem which meant that I wasn't seeing the effect that I expected with `sample:`

Answer (score 1):

We're doing something similar [here](https://github.com/artsy/eidolon/blob/c1583f7937e4696d29e7fcf106180dc4cb3cc9e3/Kiosk/Auction%20Listings/ListingsViewController.swift#L87). I'm not sure if this is the *best* approach, but it does work.

Basically, set up a recurring signal that has a 1-second interval and has `take: 10` on it so that it automatically stops. Then do a `map` on the next events from that signal, ignoring the values you're sent. Inside the `map` method, return a *new signal* that represents the work that you want carried out. Then you can just `switchToLatest` to subscribe to the objects sent by each of those signals.

Comment: Thanks Ash - but I'm not sure this correctly answers the question. What you're suggesting will carry out the work every second for 10 seconds and then stop - I think? Actually what I was asking was: say you have a signal A which fires intermittently (roughly every second or two) for now until forever. What we want is to sample signal A every 10 seconds and take from it whatever was it's last value at that point. Everything else sent since the last sample is discarded.

Comment: So say Signal A fires each second, sending [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L], if we subscribe to it we want to receive A and then (10 seconds later) K. Everything else is discarded.

Comment: I think what I'm looking for can be achieved using combineLatestWith:, I'll post back if I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

So `throttle:` is pretty much what you want. From the documentation:

> Sends `next`s only if we don't receive another `next` in `interval` seconds.
>
> If a `next` is received, and then another `next` is received before `interval` seconds have passed, the first value is discarded.
>
> After `interval` seconds have passed since the most recent `next` was sent, the most recent `next` is forwarded on the scheduler that the value was originally received on. If +[RACScheduler currentScheduler] was nil at the time, a private background scheduler is used.
>
> Returns a signal which sends throttled and delayed `next` events. Completion and errors are always forwarded immediately.

So you could chain `throttle:` and `distinctUntilChanged` to only get the most recent values.

Answer (score 0):

This is one case where you don't want to throttle to decrease the code complexity. Unfortunately, BTLE is not as efficient as once hoped. Thus, you must make manually handle the start ranging and start ranging calls yourself. The calls to CoreBluetooth still happen and expend battery life. This is equivalent to making extraneous GPS calls every meter and "dropping" them because you only needed every 10 meters. Or polling a server every 0.1 second but only responding to the 10th one.